# How can I change user position dot color in Google Maps iOS sdk 1.7?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I've just updated Google Maps sdk on my iOS app to the last version(1.7).

With the version I was using (1.6.1) the user position dot was blue, but with the new version has become gray, which I don't like and is less visible.

I was unable to find in the documentation the method to change this color, but I've found a resource in the project with the blue dot, and this make me think that is possible to change the color, but I can't find the reference on how to do this.

[image: Sprites found on Google Maps iOS sdk 1.7]

Anyone can help?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the blue dot is "on" and the gray dot is "off". In the Google Maps app, gray means it's searching for the location, blue means it found it. The Google Maps framework is a binary, so you can't change the code and I don't think there's a way to change the dot colour. Try changing the colour in Photoshop and adding it back to the resources if you really want it different.

Comment: But the location dots it's exactly on my position, it's set when I tap on my location button, and with sdk 1.6.1 was blue...